# Background task keeps blocking thread

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, q, polling

I would like to have a **background task** (can take up to a couple of minutes) in my backend **Node.js** application (provides financial market data) that collects data into a MongoDB database. Later, I also want to provide push notifications on every polling update. Therefore, I would like to keep the polling in the service.

The problem is that the background task blocks the single thread. In praxis, other functionality of the service is blocked. I'm currently considering different solutions and need help choosing the right one or a different approach.

- Scale the service to multiple instances
- Use `Q` or another promise framework
- Use `process.nextTick`
- Use the `async` framework for the loops
- Drag the polling out to an additional service
- Use something different than Node.js

Which approach would be the preferred one, if not something completely different?

This is the starting point (I did not do any optimizations yet)

I tried out the `repeat` module that takes a simple function in order to execute scheduled tasks.

```
require('repeat')(require('./lib/tasks/PollerTask.js')).every(1, 'm').start.now();
```

Below you see the actual task I am executing.

```
//...
// PollerTask.js
var providers = require('fs').readdirSync('./lib/providers').map(function (provider) {
    return require('../providers/' + provider);
});

module.exports = function() {

    // For all data providers
    _.each(providers, function (provider, done) {

        // Find all financial assets that use the data provider 
        Asset.find({ provider: provider.name }, function (err, assets) {
            // ... handle error

            // For all the assets, perform a request against the provider
            provider.getQuotes(assets, function (err, quotes) {
                // ... handle error

                // For each new quote (1 quote =^ 1 asset) 
                _.each(quotes, function (quote, done) {

                    // Append the new quote to the asset document
                    Asset.findOneAndUpdate(quote.asset,
                        { $push : { quotes : quote.quote }},
                        { safe: true, upsert: true },
                        function (err, asset) {

                            // done, notify any subscribers
                        });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What about putting the repeat statement in a other thread (not sure if this is going to help in any way): ```setTimeout(function() { require('repeat')(require('./lib/tasks/PollerTask.js')).every(1, 'm').start.now(); });```

Comment: Hi Paul, there is no other thread in Node.js, Node.js is single-threaded. I think you mean to schedule the task in the event loop. Still, this would block other requests.

Comment: Your code is showing typical asynchronous function calls, so I doubt that it's blocking. However, depending on the number of providers, the number of assets and the number of quotes, you may be overloading your system with concurrent database queries. Take a look at the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module (as you already mention) to better coordinate asynchronous tasks (`_.each()` -> `async.eachLimit()`, for instance).

Comment: I think you are right that the task is non-blocking. I have tried out your solution, it did not help. Still, any other read requests are blocked. I think the issue is the database write lock that prevents from reading from the DB. Currently, the whole task with 10-20 write operations takes 10 seconds, that's exactly the timeframe where the read is blocked. Can you tell me how to get this at scale?

Comment: Try using the OpLog and tailing for the insert/updates that you need instead of directly reading on an interval.  Also ensure you are performing your reads on the secondaries and not the master.  This will ensure your master can work on write only operations while the secondaries serve up the reads.  Sure there is a bit of a lag there, but it isn't too bad.  On a logging system with over 200k writes a second we see at most a 1 minute delay under high load.